# Código não entra no if quando deveria

Tags: javascript

Este if está correto? porque se eu retiro este IF  ele faz a chamada do ajax e envia com sucesso os campos.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick='validaFrm' value="Enviar mensagem" />
<script language="JavaScript">
function validaFrm(frm) {
    if (((frm.atividades.value !=="") && (frm.numero.value !=="") && (frm.nome.value !== "") && (frm.email.value !== "") && (frm.municipio.value !== "") && (frm.mensagem.value !== "")))
    {
         EnviaEmailInstrucao("atividades","numero","nome","email","municipio","mensagem","emailInea")
    }
    else
    {
        EnviaEmailInstrucao="Erro ao enviar";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @ramaral Perdão, estamos editando ao mesmo tempo e sobrescrevendo um ao outro.

Comment: Existe algum erro no seu console?

Comment: `frm` não está definido!

Comment: @bfavaretto Sem problema. O que interessa é que a pergunta fique com o código bem formatado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessario passar o formulario para a função `validaFrm()`, essa chamada pode ser feita no onsubmit do form. o `this` significa que vc está passando o proprio elemento(nesse caso o form) para a função.

```
<form action="suaAction" method="post" onsubmit="validaFrm(this); return false;"
```

Comment: o AJAX?

 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "<!--$HttpBrowserFullCgiPath-->",
   data: "IdcService=ENVIA_EMAIL&IsSoap=1&from=" + email +"&to=" + emailInea + "&subject=" + assunto_email + "&body=" + corpo_email
   
  }).done(function( msg ) { alert("Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso.");
  
  });